# Typescript extendable type definition

Tags: typescript

I have base type:

```
interface BaseBlockProps {
  dispatch?: PageMakerDispatch;
  ctx?: ServiceContext;
  formValues?: FieldValues;
  [propName: string]: unknown; // <-- here is the problem
}
```

Need to define this type so, that other simple type can extend it, and all it's custom props go into `Record<string, unknown>`

```
export interface TitleAndSubtitleBlockProps {
  titleText: string
  subtitleText: string
}
```

TypeScript compilation fails now with error:

```
TS2344: Type 'TitleAndSubtitleProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'BaseBlockProps'.   Index signature is missing in type 'MobileTitleAndSubtitleProps'.
```

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4VQGwPYIDWAClHgA4bIDeAUMsgCbAblxgIAWA-AFzIgArgFsARtADc9ZAjAAPPsgxgooAOZSGMPFGEA1ODkEQMi0Xjw4IcEJuQBtcmXIA5OMIj9lqkGoC6-IIghCB4AO62tAC+tLQQcuQ6YMigkLCIKAAqwGBWAIIgjADKgqJgOVa4BCTOVPGQhVToWFVEpBRUdAzluRCZ9V4q6tIYpT1W-XJggz5q0UA

Answer (score 0):

Found explanation, that desired behaviour is impossible for interface, but works for type.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend your base type, you may not need your placeholder `[propName: string]: unknown` property at all -- just explicitly add the property you need in the extended interface. For example:

```js
interface BaseBlockProps {
  dispatch?: PageMakerDispatch;
  ctx?: ServiceContext;
  formValues?: FieldValues;
}

export interface TitleAndSubtitleBlockProps extends BaseBlockProps {
  titleText: string
  subtitleText: string
}
```

As you can see, [interfaces can extend other interfaces](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/typescript/interface-extending-interfaces.html).

Comment: the thought was to combine all custom props of derived types into this record